# Error when trying to use jfoenix in scenebuilder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I'm trying to create some GUI with Jfoenix and I'm getting following errors when i run myprogram. I'm not understanding the errors .when i remove jfoenix jarfile myprogram run succesfully.
please guide me.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/BooleanConverter
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXTabPane.java:105)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane.<init>(JFXTabPane.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.BooleanConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Comment: Are you using the version of JFoenix that's compatible with JavaFX 9+?

Comment: my javafx ver is 8 and jfoenix ver ix 8.0.2 i dont know is copatible or not

Comment: The stack trace you posted indicates you're using _at least_ Java/JavaFX **9**, as it's showing _modules_ which were added in Java 9. Also, the `ClassNotFoundException` itself is a good indicator you're using a library which accessed the internals of JavaFX 8 but you're using JavaFX 9+ (a lot of code moved between FX 8 and FX 9, some to public API). If you look at the [JFoenix project's readme](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix#----) you'll see there is 8.x.x for Java 8 and 9.x.x or Java 9.